# Relay node lost after refetch

Tags: relay

I'm struggling with some weird behaviour of Relay. Basically I have a query like

```
query{
    user{
        friends{
            [Connection of friendType]
        },
        friend(id: [...]){
            [gives the friendType]
        }
    }
}
```

So there is a connection of friends, and also the possiblity to access one friend by id (to display the friends profile with some additional information). The connection works nicely, until a specific friend gets fetched by the component that shows the profile (this happens using a RelayRenderer).

The fetching of the friend works, it gets displayed... nice. But afterwards, the friends data no longer appears in the connection, the object is still present, but I can't access any of the data fetched by the component that displays the profile.

Also, even if the data displayed in the profile is the same as in the list (i.e. the fragments coincide), the profile component will fetch the friend again.

I think, this is related to the forced encapsulation by Relay. Two components display the same fragment of one particular object (the friend) but only the one, that actually fetched the data is allowed to see it.

This is counter-intuitive in my opinion, as it makes caching effectively useless since I'd have to fetch the whole connection of friends again after displaying one of them...

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT: I've been doing some research, and this is what I've seen:

The node data only gets lost, if it's a part of a fragment, i. e. if I have

```
fragment on user{
    friends { edges { node {
        id,
        name
    }
}
```

and in another place

```
fragment on user {
    friend(id: [...]) {
        id,
        name
    }
}
```

then querying the second fragment breaks the first one, the list (using the first fragment) doesn't get any access to node.name. If on the other hand both fragments use a nested

`fragment on friend {name}`

then it works.

This however is very tedious, as it means splitting up Relay containers on the level of individual Texts (in some cases).

Comment: Relay is not supposed to behave this way. How does your node definition look like for `friendType `?

Comment: basically friendType contains a whole buch of scalars, like name, picture, ... I have decided to switch to Apollo Client though; that is probably more suited to my style of programming.

Comment: I was actually talking about node definition of friendType (on the server side). In Relay, the types' id is vital and it takes some time to understand how it works in Relay. Anyway, I'm glad that Apollo client library worked for you.

Comment: What do you mean by node definition? Do you mean the node interface required by Relay? That is implemented as in the specification

Comment: Yes, something like https://github.com/relayjs/relay-examples/blob/3695905911b176dc04d146ff789ba7f41f156a18/star-wars/data/schema.js#L124-L138 . The type of problem you posted usually happens when there's a problem in node definition or unique node ID generation.

Comment: Okay, I don't think there is a problem there. I'm using ArangoDB which has globally unique ids by default, so there is no generation mechanism involved.. But that doesn't matter to me anymore, since I've switched. Nonetheless thank you!